PlotRange in AudioPlot
Given this audio file:
AudioFile
The command
AudioPlot[audio, PlotRange -> {Quantity[200, "ms"], Quantity[11000, "ms"]}]

Yields

Which is perfectly fine. But I would expect that
AudioPlot[audio, PlotRange -> {Quantity[10000, "ms"], Quantity[11000, "ms"]}]

with the same data yields a zoom in of those signals at the end. The resulting plot is:

which is a little bit puzzling to me? Why? What to do to get the segment with the signal plotted?
$Version

is
"14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"
Any hints on this?

I see the audio plot shifted compared to your first image. The loud part for me is AudioPlot[audio,   PlotRange -> {Quantity[9200, "ms"], Quantity[9800, "ms"]}].
